# Product alert e-mail with more than one product listed

Tags: product, ce-1.9.0.1, product-collection, alert

Can you guys give me an example of how a product alert e-mail can dispatch **more than one product** alert in a single e-mail ?

It seems to this point that each product a single customer is subscribed generates one e-mail, one for each product, and so the product collection on `stock.phtml` foreach loop always has only one product.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The e-mail is not sent immediately after a product gets back in stock (or the price is lowered).

There is a cron job that does the sending. You can configure the time when this runs from the backend.

Here is a scenario.
You subscribe for the stock alert for 2 products.
The products come back in stock both at the same time (or very close).
The next time the cron runs sees that you need to get 2 products in your e-mail and groups them both in the same e-mail.
See how the grouping is done in `Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Observer::_processStock`

Comment: Hi. I tested that scenario too. Each row was invoked individually for the same e-mail and I got 2 e-mails to registered user instead of one.

Comment: @Niloct. Damn. Which version? I remember working with this a long time ago and it worked. I will test again.

Comment: Latest. But you may be right, I tested guest e-mails, which Amasty allows. Will try a registered user alert now.

Comment: Well... I suspended cron altering `crontab/jobs/catalog_product_alert/schedule/cron_expr`, emptied stock of 2 products, added 2 notifications of same customer, restocked 2 products and reenabled cron, I got two e-mails.

Comment: ok. I'll give it a shot myself and come back with the results.

Comment: Just tested on 1.7.0.2. Only one e-mail is sent. I will check on 1.9.0.1. You said you have an extension installed to allow guest subscriptions. Disable that and try again, maybe it's interfering somehow.

Comment: @Niloct I've tested on 1.9.0.1 with 3 products at once. One single e-mail received. My money is on the extension causing this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15911/discussion-between-niloct-and-marius).

Comment: If there any chance the module causes the several email sending just email to Amasty with the link to this tread. You have free support warranty with the module (I assume it's Out of Stock Subscription Notification).  There was a discussion about paid modules support at stackexchange.

Comment: Yes @Amasty it seems v.1.2.1 has this problem. Can you test with latest Magento ? I can't share FTP access as you usually ask in support.

Comment: @Amasty see chat.